# Custom Listview laggy when there's an if statement

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an custom list view.
it is laggy when if comes to the conditional statements part

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View caloocanView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (caloocanView == null)

            caloocanView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.caloocan_list_view, parent, false);
        restauInfoDB restaurant = Restau.get(position);
        //ImageView from URL
        holder.restauIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(restaurant.getUrl()).centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.six)
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.restauIcon);


        String x = "N";
        Double hotCTR = 15.0;
        String New = "N";


        holder.healthyIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.healthyIcon);
        //HEALTHY
        if (x.equals(restaurant.getHealthy())) {

            holder.healthyIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.healthyIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //NEW
        if (New.equals(restaurant.getNew())){
            holder.newLabel = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.newLabel);
            holder.newLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.newLabel = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.newLabel);
            holder.newLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        //HOT
        if (hotCTR <= Double.valueOf(restaurant.getRating())) {
            holder.hotIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.iconHot);
            holder.hotIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.hotIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.iconHot);
            holder.hotIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }



        String serving = "Serving: ";
        // RESTAU NAME
        holder.restauName = (TextView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.resnameTxt);
        holder.restauName.setText(restaurant.getResname());
        //FOOD TYPE

        holder.oh = (TextView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.ophrTxt);
        holder.oh.setText("Operating Hours: " +restaurant.getOh());



        holder.resloc = (TextView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.reslocTxt);
        holder.resloc.setText(restaurant.getResloc());
        return caloocanView;



    }`
```

and this is the static viewHolder

```
static class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView restauIcon;
    ImageView healthyIcon;
    ImageView newLabel;
    ImageView hotIcon;
    TextView restauName;
    TextView oh;
    TextView resloc;
}
```

Comment: `if (true) { }` - that won't make anything laggy. So the question isn't about an `if` at all.. either 1) the condition in the `if` is "taking so much time that makes the operation laggy" or 2) the code inside an `if` is "slow enough such that it makes the operation laggy". In either case, isolating exactly *which* code is slow or causes the issue is important.

Comment: @user2864740 my custom listView is lagging when the statements are true. it shows pictures in the list which makes it laggy. but when it is false. it is not

Comment: Try using a RecyclerView instead since you didn't implement ViewHolder pattern correctly

Comment: @cricket_007 is it hard migrating from custom listview to recyclerView ?

Comment: In my opinion, no, but you should look up the proper way to use the ViewHolder pattern for Listview  first.

Comment: is my ViewHolder patter for lview is wrong ? or not in proper form?

Comment: Compare here.  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#improving-performance-with-the-viewholder-pattern ... Notice the setTag usage

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the point of using ViewHolder,the point is to minimize inflating new layouts and finding views in layout which are time consuming and make view laggy,but you are calling `findViewById()` every time.

try this code instead:

```
            View caloocanView = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            if (caloocanView == null) {
                caloocanView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.caloocan_list_view, parent, false);
                holder.restauIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                holder.healthyIcon = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.healthyIcon);
                holder.newLabel = (ImageView) caloocanView.findViewById(R.id.newLabel);
                ...
                caloocanView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) caloocanView.getTag();
            }
            ...

            //HEALTHY
            if (x.equals(restaurant.getHealthy())) {

                holder.healthyIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.healthyIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

and reformat rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your RecyclerView layout xml:

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

It may be not affect older versions of Android, but in newer versions the lag is completely gone.

EDIT:by RecyclerView, I mean ListView

Comment: The question is using a ListView, not a RecyclerView

Comment: I think it's also usable in ListView, but not yet found the official documentation

Comment: I'm not sure how that fixes lagginess considering there is nothing scrollable that is nested

Comment: Android doesn't automatically know (yet) that the ListView do or doesn't have a nested scrollable child, so I think, with mentioning that it doesn't in the first place, the machine will ignore the checking process.

I haven't studied deep enough yet. But by my experience, it does hugely decrease chance of lag in scrollable (including RecyclerView, ListView, etc)